# How can I assign a callback function to an asp:HyperlinkField?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, callback, hyperlink

I want people to click on a link (generated from an asp:HyperlinkField) and have it call a method on the server rather than redirect the user somewhere. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an asp:CommandField or asp:ButtonField instead and use ButtonType=Link - that will look the same as your linkfield, and then you can handle the OnRowCommand event in your grid to run your code.

Comment: yes you're right, no need to add a template column (like my answer), this one is very easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an asp:LinkButton instead.  Unless there's a particular reason you're attached to the asp:Hyperlink?

Comment: Nope, no reason, just didn't want it to look like a button. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HyperLinkField is used for generating simple hyperlinks in databound controls. Instead you can use [ButtonField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.aspx). Or you can define your own link with [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx).

Here is a sample of generating link column which has a server side event :

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="Link Column">
    <itemtemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="myLink" 
            CommandName="MyLinkCommand" 
            CommandArgument='<%#Bind("TableID") %>'
            runat="server">My Link</asp:LinkButton>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

At code behind :

```
protected void YouGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "MyLinkCommand")
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a ButtonField instead and set the [ButtonType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfieldbase.buttontype.aspx) to a Link?  It will look just like a hyperlink.